# Build SCAP files from reference system

Tags: openscap

The current way of dealing with a SCAP configuration file is unwieldy.  Let's look at the process as I read it in the documentation:

1. Take a starting config file (CIS, DISA STIG, OpenSCAP reference)
2. Make changes manually to reflect reference at our organization.

The problem with this that it represents a great deal of manual (error-prone) work.  I did a test with a CIS SCAP file and scanned our reference OS and there were 325 differences.  Multiply this by Windows, CentOS/Red Hat, and Ubuntu and version updates with new config options as time passes.  And this is not counting ay local changes in config that occur.  We need a good fraction of a FTE just to manage this.  We do not have the person-time to make this happen.

What I am looking for is a tool that will take a reference (gold) system and build the config file.  When we change the gold image, we just rebuild the config from the new image.

Does such a tool exist?

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered `xmldiff`?